# Reference parent query column in subquery (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, subquery

How can I reference a column outside of a subquery using Oracle?  I specifically need to use it in the WHERE statement of the subquery.

Basically I have this:

```
SELECT Item.ItemNo, Item.Group
FROM Item
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT Attribute.Group, COUNT(1) CT 
                   FROM Attribute 
                   WHERE Attribute.ItemNo=12345) A ON A.Group = Item.Group
WHERE Item.ItemNo=12345
```

I'd like to change `WHERE Attribute.ItemNo=12345` to `WHERE Attribute.ItemNo=Item.ItemNo` in the subquery, but I can't figure out if this is possible.  I keep getting "ORA-00904: 'Item'.'ItemNo': Invalid Identifier"

**EDIT:**

Ok, this is why I need this kind of structure:

I want to be able to get a count of the "Error" records (where the item is missing a value) and the "OK" records (where the item has a value).

The way I have set it up in the fiddle returns the correct data.  I think I might just end up filling in the value in each of the subqueries, since this would probably be the easiest way. Sorry if my data structures are a little convoluted.  I can explain if need be.

My tables are:

```
create table itemcountry(
  itemno number,
  country nchar(3),
  imgroup varchar2(10),
  imtariff varchar2(20),
  exgroup varchar2(10),
  extariff varchar2(20) );

create table itemattribute(
  attributeid varchar2(10),
  tariffgroup varchar2(10),
  tariffno varchar2(10) );

create table icav(
  itemno number,
  attributeid varchar2(10),
  value varchar2(10) );
```

and my query so far is:

```
select itemno, country, imgroup, imtariff, im.error "imerror", im.ok "imok", exgroup, extariff, ex.error "exerror", ex.ok "exok"
from itemcountry
  left outer join (select sum(case when icav.itemno is null then 1 else 0 end) error, sum(case when icav.itemno is not null then 1 else 0 end) ok, tariffgroup, tariffno
                   from itemattribute ia 
                     left outer join icav on ia.attributeid=icav.attributeid 
                   where (icav.itemno=12345 or icav.itemno is null) 
                   group by tariffgroup, tariffno) im on im.tariffgroup=imgroup and imtariff=im.tariffno
  left outer join (select sum(case when icav.itemno is null then 1 else 0 end) error, sum(case when icav.itemno is not null then 1 else 0 end) ok, tariffgroup, tariffno
                   from itemattribute ia 
                     left outer join icav on ia.attributeid=icav.attributeid 
                   where (icav.itemno=12345 or icav.itemno is null) 
                   group by tariffgroup, tariffno) ex on ex.tariffgroup=exgroup and extariff=ex.tariffno
where itemno=12345;
```

It's also set up in a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/424e7/7).

Comment: you can't.. what do you want to select? may have another solution other than left outer join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in a sub-query but not in a join. In your case I don't see any need to. You can put it in the join condition.

```
select i.itemno, i.group
  from item i
  left outer join ( select group, itemno
                      from attribute b
                     group by group itemno ) a
    on a.group = i.group 
   and i.itemno = a.itemno
 where i.itemno = 12345
```

The optimizer is built to deal with this sort of situation so utilise it!

I've changed the `count(1)` to a `group by` as you need to `group by` all columns that aren't aggregated.

I'm assuming that your actual query is more complicated than this as with the columns you're selecting this is probably equivilent to

```
select itemno, group
  from item
 where itemno = 12345
```

You could also write your sub-query with an [`analytic function`](http://psoug.org/reference/analytic_functions.html) instead. Something like `count(*) over ( partition by group)`.

As an aside using a keyword as a column name, in this case `group` is A Bad Idea <sup>TM</sup>. It can cause a lot of confusion. As you can see from the code above you have a lot of `groups` in there.

---

So, based on your SQL-Fiddle, which I've added to the question I think you're looking for something like the following, which doesn't look much better. I suspect, given time, I could make it simpler. On another side note explicitly lower casing queries is never worth the hassle it causes. I've followed your naming convention though.

```
with sub_query as (
 select count(*) - count(icav.itemno) as error
      , count(icav.itemno) as ok
      , min(itemno) over () as itemno
      , tariffgroup
      , tariffno
   from itemattribute ia 
   left outer join icav 
     on ia.attributeid = icav.attributeid 
  group by icav.itemno
         , tariffgroup
         , tariffno
  ) 
    select ic.itemno, ic.country, ic.imgroup, ic.imtariff
         , sum(im.error) as "imerror", sum(im.ok) as "imok"
         , ic.exgroup, ic.extariff
         , sum(ex.error) as "exerror", sum(ex.ok) as "exok"
      from itemcountry ic
      left outer join sub_query im 
        on ic.imgroup = im.tariffgroup
       and ic.imtariff = im.tariffno
       and ic.itemno = im.itemno
      left outer join sub_query ex 
        on ic.exgroup = ex.tariffgroup
       and ic.extariff = ex.tariffno
       and ic.itemno = ex.itemno
     where ic.itemno = 12345
     group by ic.itemno, ic.country
            , ic.imgroup, ic.imtariff
            , ic.exgroup, ic.extariff
           ;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those analytic functions.  You're right, I was trying to recreate the example as simply as possible.  A better representation of my end goal is in the sqlfiddle I added in the edit.

Comment: @tedski, my answer still stands! Using a less complicated example is standard practice, it makes life easier for all. You can still put your condition in the join...

Comment: Sorry, my example didn't capture my problem correctly.  There's another table being joined in the subquery and there are actually two counts.  I have a count of when the item in the joined table is null and when it isn't.  If I added the item number in, it would spit out two columns instead of one.

Answer (score -4):

You can put WHERE attribute.itemno=item.itemno inside the subquery.  You are going to filter the data anyway, filtering the data inside the subquery is usually faster too.